# How to limit number of transposed variables in proc transpose SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I am transposing a file with several million observations using

```
proc transpose data=click out=CLICK_transp name=test prefix=var;
by ComlogId;        
var clickthrulink_Description;
run;
```

However, this job takes a long time to run because some of the clickthrulink_Description have up to hundreds of observations. I need to limit the transposed variable down to 6. Is there any way to do that in SAS and would that be more efficient in terms of run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

First off, you could use a KEEP statement in the output.

```
proc transpose in=have out=want(keep=id col1-col6);
by id;
var myvar;
run;
```

This would limit what's written to the output dataset, which would limit its size greatly.

You also could use `options compress=yes;` which would help with your bigger issue - lots of blank data.  That would significantly decrease the amount of size needed to store the observations with much fewer than the maximum number of columns.

Finally, you could limit things with a view:

```
data v_have/view=v_have;
set have;
by id;
if first.id then counter=0;
counter+1;
if counter<6;
run;

proc transpose data=v_have out=want;
by id;
var yourvar;
run;
```

That would only pass the first six observations per ID to the transpose procedure.

Comment: Thanks! The keep and nocompress option took 17 minutes to run, which improves efficiency drastically. But limiting with the view took me down to 1.29 second!! :-)

Comment: Interesting - that confirms what I guessed, that keep wouldn't affect the work TRANSPOSE was doing internally, only affect the size of the output dataset (which is a big factor certainly).

Answer (score -1):

You can choose 6 variable trought the data step firstly:

```
DATA newClick(obs=6);
SET click;
RUN;
```

and then use the transpose procedure with a new data newClick.

Comment: Read the OP's code above.  The OP has a vertical dataset, transposing from one variable (plus ID) long form to horizontal form.

Comment: @Joe, this code only for choosing these 6 variables; and then he should use the transpose procedure.

Comment: Except the OP doesn't have six variables.  The OP has six _rows_ that will become variables after transpose.

Comment: @Joe, OK. So we can you option obs=6 in data set for this case at all.

Comment: Except that would only include 6 observations total; he wants six observations _per ComlogID_.  Look at my answer; the view is the simplest method to accomplish this limitation.